# If statement error in Firebird

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

My table has this structure `T_user(usern,pass,realname: varchar(50);`
I am a beginner in Firebird and I want to execute the following statements, but I get this error:

```
if (select Count(*) as cnt FROM T_USER WHERE ( usern = 'test') And (pass
= ']')) > 0  then  select T_user.realname from t_user where t_user.usern = 'test';
```

This is the  error message:

> Error:  IBPP::SQLException  Context: Statement::Prepare( if
>   (select Count(*) as cnt FROM T_USER WHERE ( usern = 'test') And (pass
>   = ']')) > 0  then   select T_user.realname from t_user where t_user.usern = 'test' ) Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
>
> SQL Message : -104 Invalid token
>
> Engine Code    : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL
>   error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 1 if

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and FlameRobin.

Comment: You can't use `IF` in a query, only in PSQL (a procedure or `EXECUTE BLOCK`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
  RETURNS (name VARCHAR(50))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE C INTEGER;
BEGIN
  select Count(*) 
  FROM T_USER 
  WHERE  usern = 'test' And pass = ']'
  INTO :C;

  IF (:C > 0) THEN
    select T_user.realname 
    from t_user 
    where t_user.usern = 'test'
    into :name;
  ELSE
    name = NULL;

  SUSPEND;
END
```

Comment: `SUSPEND` isn't necessary here, as it will only return one row.

Comment: @Andrej : Could you please show me a sample also with input parameters? because I tried this below but it gives me an error;
EXECUTE BLOCK (username varchar (50), password varchar(50)) 
  RETURNS (name VARCHAR(50))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE C INTEGER;  
BEGIN
  select Count(*) 
  FROM T_USER 
  WHERE  usern = :username And pass = :password
  INTO :C;

  IF (:C > 0) THEN
    select T_user.realname
    from t_user 
    where t_user.usern = :utilizator
    into :name;
  ELSE
    name = NULL;
  SUSPEND;
END;

Answer (score -1):

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM T_USER
    WHERE (USERN = 'test')
          AND (PASS = ']')) > 0) THEN
  SELECT T_USER.REALNAME
  FROM T_USER
  WHERE T_USER.USERN = 'test';
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.